# Numbers not sorting dates correctly

Tags: numbers, sort

I cannot get the column to sort the dates correctly in Numbers!  I want to sort the column by date and instead of sorting 1 through 12, it sorts like this: `1,10,11,12,2,3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort column by date in Numbers?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144946/how-to-sort-column-by-date-in-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you type in your dates in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. For example `01/01/2019` `02/01/2019` `03/01/2019`

The right-click the column at the top and click Sort Ascending.

[image]

Then your dates should be sorted in ascending order:

[image]

Comment: Or better in iso format 2018-12-25